# Click a button with a span class

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to click on this link (to the side of it there's an icon with a download button) "Save / Print this bill (pdf)

I appreciate any help, as this is the final steps and thank you in advance.

I tried:

($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID(‘save_desktop’) | select -first 1).click()

($ie.document.getElementById("save_desktop") | select -first 1).click()

From the DOM explorer:

```
> <span class="tip ng-binding" id="save_desktop" style="color: black
> !important;">Save / Print this bill (PDF)</span>
> 
> <i class="cus-icon-download"></i>   (This is the button beside the
> link as well which would give the drop down options)
```

Error in PS:

> > ($ie.document.getElementById("save_desktop") | select -first 1).click()
> >     Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
> >     At line:2 char:1
> >     + ($ie.document.getElementById("save_desktop") | select -first 1).click ...
> >     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >         + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException

Comment: Are you sure that the code is being executed after the document is fully loaded? Try adding `while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; }` to your code. You can vary the seconds if the browser is loading slow.

Comment: Yep, it's fully loaded. I even have the PS terminal up with the page loaded executing the one line to see if that link/button would be clicked when running the command. I have a Start-Sleep -Seconds after each code too, just in case. I tried the above, no luck.