# Click on a button with powershell automation

Tags: html, powershell, com

Unable to click on a button, everything I tried does not work.

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("save_desktop").click()
```

and

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | where-object {$_.type -eq "Save / Print this bill (PDF)"}
$Link.click();
```

and

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('save_desktop') | select -first 1).click()
```

It takes the first part, but it does not like the .click, I've tried .submit as well, nothing seems to work!

```
<span class="tip ng-binding" id="save_desktop" style="color: black
!important;">Save / Print this bill (PDF)</span>
```

Errors:

> You cannot call a null expression
>
> Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a
>   method named 'click'. At line:1 char:1
>   + $ie.Document.getElementById('save_desktop').Click()

I've added more info:

---

```
> <span class="print-save-pdf-link ng-scope"
> ng-click="bbTrackData('events',true,'bill:save:print this bill')"
> tooltip-trigger="click" tooltip-placement="bottom-left"
> tooltip-html-unsafe="<div
> class=&quot;downloadPdfEbuText&quot;>Download:</div><div
> class=&quot;d-iflex&quot;><i
> class=&quot;cus-icon-rogers_overlay-arrow-circle&quot;></i><span
> onclick=&quot;downloadCompleteBill('14161234567-123456789')&quot;
> class=&quot;downloadPdfEbuLink-rogers&quot;>Complete
> bill</span></div><div class=&quot;d-iflex&quot;><i
> class=&quot;cus-icon-rogers_overlay-arrow-circle&quot;></i><span
> onclick=&quot;downloadAccountSummary('1-1234-5678','24092019')&quot;
> class=&quot;downloadPdfEbuLink-rogers&quot;>Account
> summary</span></div>"><i class="cus-icon-download"></i><span
> class="tip ng-binding" id="save_desktop" style="color: black
> !important;">Save / Print this bill (PDF)</span></span>
```

---

Comment: This should work, `($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('save_desktop') | select -first 1).click()` I have tested this line against a test document and it works as expected and fires an `onclick` event, so I don't think there is anything wrong with your code per se. Can you confirm the object type you have by running `($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('save_desktop') | select -first 1).getType()`. Additionally are you certain that this `span` is the element to click, and that there isn't something surrounding it like an anchor?

Comment: I see you have [asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228935/click-a-button-with-a-span-class), but received no answer. I think you should show more of the HTML so we can figure out if the `<span>` is surrounded by a `<a href=...` anchor (link) tag or if the span has an `onclick=...` event handler specified.

Comment: I've tried these as well, with no luck.

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ ($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('save_desktop') | select  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: The get type gives me: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ ($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('save_desktop') | select  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: I've added more info at the top, thanks everyone.